# CType not showing up in dropdown, TYPO3 version 11.5.23

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

I try to create my extension. The extension is called personal. So I use the `personal_` prefix for the CType.

TYPO3 has version 11.5.23

For the dropdown, I think the only thing I have to do is to create the tt_content.php

I tried this guide:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/ContentElements/AddingYourOwnContentElements.html

Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php

```
  // Add the content element to the "Type" dropdown
  \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTcaSelectItem(
      'tt_content',
      'CType',
      [
          'Titel',
          'personal_titel',
          'content-text',
      ],
      'textmedia',
      'after'
  );
```

But when I choose it from the wizard, the CType is unknown.
[image: The dropdown for CTypes shows "INVALID VALUE(personal_titel)"]

Comment: Quick guess: you have a typo in the CType: in your code snippet you write `personal_titel` but the screenshot says `perosonal_titel`.

Comment: oh yeah, I didn't fix the typo in the image, but the problem still exists. I fixed the image, too

Comment: Not sure if it is a dependency, but have you already added your new CType as a new type of record? https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/ContentElements/AddingYourOwnContentElements.html#configure-the-backend-form

Comment: Cleared the cache?

Comment: @ThomasLöffler Yeah cache is cleared.

Comment: @JulianHofmann In that step, I realized that this didn't work. I thought it worked before that step so I removed that form again.

Comment: Just to be sure: your extension/package is active/installed? Try searching your CType in BE "System > Configuration: TCA". Is there an entry below `tt_content.columns.CType.items` containing your new CType?

Comment: @JulianHofmann The extension is active. I have no menu point below "System", which is called "Configuration". I have a `ddev composer` setup. If it is important.

Comment: "Configuration" is a part of package `typo3/cms-lowlevel`. IMO helpful at least as a dev-requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fundamental. I think that is why nobody could give me a solution.

Just putting `<?php` at the head of the file solved the problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

Had that behaviour once i had limited the allowed CEs of the content column (maybe you use grielements or sth elese).

I had to explicitly allow my CE in the content column config and after clearing the cache it worked. Maybe it helps in your case, too?

Comment: How do I explicitly allow the CE in the content column config?

Comment: Look at [this](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/gridelements/stable/Chapters/GridTsSyntax/Index.html#create-the-cells) - you should look for the `allowed` or `disallowed` line and change accordingly. 


If you don't use EXT:gridelements you can try EXT:[content_defender](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/content_defender/) it will also [allow/disallow](https://github.com/IchHabRecht/content_defender/blob/main/README.md) content types.